# Adding layout to a scrollview gets eaten up

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

I have a layout something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:background="#ff303f"
    android:id="@+id/layout">
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/picture"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancel"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/picture"
        android:background="@drawable/cross_out"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I inflate it using the usual layout inflator service, set up some functionality to the button and an image to the imageview (all images are of same size and aspect ratio).

After that, I add this view to my fragment's layout which is nothing but a ScrollView which is a parent, it has a child linear layout that I call 'map' and simply add it to the map.

Expected : The added layouts should get added properly and I can scroll through it.
Actual : If more than 2 are added, the first one gets eaten up. I can see it half or sometimes it is completely eaten up. :\

Any idea whats going on here? Thanks a lot for your time.

EDIT:
Here's the layout file I add the inflated layout into:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#f6ff45">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#43ff44"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I also forgot to mention that after adding 3 or more of these layouts, I realized there's unnecessary empty space in the end. :\

Comment: is the LinearLayout that you are using as child of the ScrollView, vertical or horizontal ?

Comment: Please post also your ScrollView's XML details

Comment: I've now posted the main layout file, please check it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have some `android:layout_gravity` or `gravity` property in your ScrollView, that may be the reason. Try deleting it, or make it `center_horizontal`.

Comment: I've now posted the main layout file, please check it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for your layout file;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#f6ff45">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#43ff44"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

As I mentioned before, `android:layout_gravity="center"`in this LinearLayout causes this problem. Because it doesn't only horizontally center but also verticelly center the contents. It means when they are longer than the available height, the center part will appear. I only changed it into `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"` and the problem is fixed.